# Grameen Phone ZTE modem is not detected in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, usb-modem, modem, zte

I have a ZTE modem from grameen phone. But it doesn't work in ubuntu 14.04. Works fine in all the distributions of Windows. The problem is when I insert the modem I cannot see a device in the menu. If I could have seen the menu, I could have installed the required driver from the modem's storage.

I have tried using sakis3g script. But it cannot connect the modem.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does the modem have a linux driver on it?

Comment: It should have. But the problem is, it is not detected as usb storage either.

Comment: the cricket mobel modem I had required a driver for that too. If you have access to a windows machine and a USB stick. you could copy the drivers off of the dongle and install manually.

Comment: I thought doing so. But problem is I don't have any windows machine right now. :(

Comment: @ravery is there any download link for ZTE modem drivers?